# Codeigniter - How to select row id's of matching date column in query

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I am trying to write a query that outputs the shiftId's into an array. 
I have a table that looks like this.

```
+---------+----------+-------+
| shiftId | endTime  | shift |
+---------+----------+-------+
|       1 | 03/03/19 |     1 |
|       2 | 03/03/19 |     2 |
|       3 | 03/01/19 |     1 |
|       4 | 03/01/19 |     2 |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

I want to return the shiftId of each date with the largest shift, and not sure how to go about.

I want my array to look like below, based on above table.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
)
```

I have tried to group_by date and then select_max of each shift but don't think I'm on the correct path. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to select shiftId foreach date where shift # is the largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **were** on the right path!

Either use (this shows the SQL more clearly):

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT max(shiftId) shiftId FROM yourtable GROUP BY endTime')->result_array();
```

Or (if you want to use CI's query builder):

```
$query = $this->db->select_max('shiftId')->group_by('endTime')->get('yourtable')->result_array();
```

Both of these group the table by `endTime`, and then return the maximum `shiftId` for each group of identical `endTime`s. Both give an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [shiftId] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [shiftId] => 4
        )

)
```

To get rid of the `shiftId` index in the result and get the exact array structure from your OP, use:

`array_column($query, 'shiftId');`

**Edit**

If you want to get the `shiftId` for each `endTime` + `MAX(shift)` combination, use this:

```
SELECT shiftId FROM yourtable
WHERE CONCAT(endTime, "-", shift) IN (
    SELECT CONCAT(endTime, "-", MAX(shift)) FROM yourtable GROUP BY endTime
)
```

The inner query (after `IN`) does more or less the same as the previous query: it groups the records in the table by `endTime`, then gets the maximum `shift` for each group of identical `endTime`s, and here it concatenates this with the `endTime` and a dash.

You need to concatenate `endTime` with `MAX(shift)` here, because `MAX(shift)` alone is not unique in the table (there's more than one shift with number 2, for example), and neither is `endTime`.

The outer query (`SELECT shiftId`...) then finds the matching `shiftId` for each `endTime` + `MAX(shift)` combination and returns that.

You need to use two (nested) queries for this, because the inner one uses grouping and the outer one doesn't, and you're not allowed to mix those two types in one query.

Note: `CONCAT` only works in MySQL, if you're using a different database type, you might have to look up what concatenation syntax it uses (could be `+` or `||` for example).

In CI:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT shiftId FROM yourtable
WHERE CONCAT(endTime, "-", shift) IN (SELECT CONCAT(endTime, "-", MAX(shift)) FROM yourtable GROUP BY endTime)')->result_array();
```

Comment: I think I spoke to soon. This worked in this scenario but doesn't work shifts are in different order. I am actually trying to get the shiftId where shift is max.           
 $this->db->select('shiftId, MAX(shift)')->group_by('DATE(endTime)')->get('richShift')->result_array(); but this returns an error

Comment: Updated my post with a new query, hopefully this'll do what you need. :)

Comment: This does work but, I how do I format the date in sql? I tried formatting as DATE(endTime) but it returns a db error. Here is my statement.        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT shiftId FROM richShift WHERE CONCAT(DATE(endTime), "-", shift) IN (SELECT CONCAT(DATE(endTime), "-", MAX(shift)) FROM richShift GROUP BY DATE(endTime))')->result_array();

Comment: What format does your `endTime` column use? Your query (with the added `DATE()`) works for me, when using either `DATE` type or `DATETIME` type for the `endTime` column.

Comment: My column is a DATETIME. Here is the error "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'intranet.richShift.endTime' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT shiftId FROM richShift WHERE CONCAT(DATE(endTime), "-", shift) IN (SELECT CONCAT(DATE(endTime), "-", MAX(shift)) FROM richShift GROUP BY DATE(endTime))

Comment: Apparently there's a bug in MySQL when using `CONCAT` in combination with `only_full_group_by` mode that prevents this query from working even though the syntax is correct, see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90792&thanks=4 I can't think of another solution to your problem, is there any chance you are allowed to turn off the `only_full_group_by` mode?

Comment: This worked, I just turned off sql_mode=only_full_group_by. Thanks for all the help really appreciate it.